# Reading my text file in a loop does not receive successive data items

Tags: c++

I am trying to read numbers off of a file but when I read it from a loop, it doesn't move to the next line. I have tried moving my ".open" outside of the loop like I had before but that results in a "core dump" error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I am very new please don't be too harsh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int Array [14], SecondArray [7];
double loop = 1;

class Payroll {
public:
  double hourlyrate;
  double hours;

    Payroll (double Hourlyrate, double Hours){
      hourlyrate = Hourlyrate;
      hours = Hours;
  }
};



int main() { 
  int copy1;
  int finder;
  
  ifstream info;
  info.open("payroll.dat");

  
  while (loop < 15){
    info >> copy1;
    Array[finder] = Array[finder] + copy1;
    
    Payroll Emp1 (Array [0] , Array [1]);
    Payroll Emp2 (Array [2] , Array [3]);
    Payroll Emp3 (Array [4] , Array [5]);
    Payroll Emp4 (Array [6] , Array [7]);
    Payroll Emp5 (Array [8] , Array [9]);
    Payroll Emp6 (Array [10] , Array [11]);
    Payroll Emp7 (Array [12] , Array [13]);


    //info check
    cout << Emp1.hourlyrate << " and " << Emp1.hours << endl; 
    cout << copy1 << endl;

    loop = loop + 1;
    finder = finder + 1;

    }
  }
```

my file has 14 values. It should be reading them and copying them to "copy1" to be processed but all it does is read the first value if it's in the loop but doesn't work outside of the loop. If there are any optimizations that I could make otherwise I'll gladly listen to them. (I have yet to clean it up)
My file contains numbers on seperate lines. Here are the numbers copy and pasted from the file:

```
40.0 
10.00
38.5
9.50 
16.0 
7.50 
22.5
9.50
40.0
8.00
38.0
8.00
40.0
9.00
```

All I get when I try to copy is `40`.

Comment: `finder` is not before the first read access initialized resulting in UB. Why is `loop` a `double` btw? Why is it a global? Why do you use 2 separate loop variables?

Comment: use std::vector

Comment: @fabian Moving finder fixed the error but it still will not read the next data. Should loop be something else? And what would changing it do? As for loop and finder both being there I just had it to test but you are right I should fix that.

Comment: @pm100 Thank you for the response. what would a vector change?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel My file contains numbers on seperate lines. Here are the numbers copy and pasted from the file. 40.0 
10.00
38.5 
9.50
16.0
7.50
22.5 
9.50
40.0 
8.00
38.0 
8.00
40.0
9.00
All I get when I try to copy is "40". Should I put them in a series and if so what would I change to read them? And what was wrong with how I had them?

Comment: Why are you creating 7 objects of type `Payroll` in every single loop iteration, but then only using one of these objects? This does not make sense to me.

Comment: std::vector is memory safe and dynamically sized

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to initailize your two variables at the start of main:

```
  int copy1;
  int finder;
```

Because they could be any value and when doing:

```
Array[finder] = Array[finder] + copy1;
```

You could be accessing out of the bounds of the array. You could be doing this:

```
  Array[0] ...;
```

or this, it is UB(undefined behaviour):

```
Array[252464] ...;
```

So you should initialize the two variables like this

```
  int copy1 = 0;
  int finder = 0;
```

You should also not declare the `loop` as global or a `double`. Declare it in the main function like this:

```
int loop = 0;
```

You could also do:

```
loop++;
```

Loop and finder will always be the same values, so there is no point making another variable that will be the same as another variable.

You should also check to see if your file is valid:

```
  if(!info)
    return -1;
```

So your complete program would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string> // getline, stoi
using namespace std; // shouldn't really use using namespace std


int Array [14], SecondArray [7];

class Payroll {
public:
  double hourlyrate;
  double hours;

    Payroll (double Hourlyrate, double Hours){
      hourlyrate = Hourlyrate;
      hours = Hours;
  }
};



int main() { 
  int copy1 = 0;
  int loop = 0;
  
  ifstream info;
  info.open("payroll.dat");

  if(!info)
    return -1; // file is not found.
  
  while (loop < 14){ // initailized loop with 0 instead of  
    string s{};
    getline(info, s);
    copy1 = stoi(s);

    Array[loop] = Array[loop] + copy1;
    
    Payroll Emp1 (Array [0] , Array [1]);// should really use a std container
    Payroll Emp2 (Array [2] , Array [3]);
    Payroll Emp3 (Array [4] , Array [5]);
    Payroll Emp4 (Array [6] , Array [7]);
    Payroll Emp5 (Array [8] , Array [9]);
    Payroll Emp6 (Array [10] , Array [11]);
    Payroll Emp7 (Array [12] , Array [13]);


    //info check
    cout << Emp1.hourlyrate << " and " << Emp1.hours << "\n"; 
    cout << copy1 << "\n"; // use "\n" instead of endl;

    loop++; // instead of loop = loop + 1;
    // dont need other loop count
    }
  }
```

**Edit**:
Also make sure to default initialize `Array`. C++ does not set array elements to 0 for you, so you'll have to do that yourself. This is important because you're doing `Array[finder] = Array[finder] + copy1`, and since `Array[finder]` is not already set to 0, you won't know what result you get.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249379/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-shepherd-reading-my-text-file-in-a-loop-does-not).